# SQL: How to Order By And Limit Via a Join

Tags: sql, postgresql

As an example, let's say I have the following query:

```
select
  u.id,
  u.name,
  (select s.status from user_status s where s.user_id = u.id order by s.created_at desc limit 1) as status
from
  user u
where
  u.active = true;
```

The above query works great. It returns the most recent user status for the selected user. However, I want to know how to get the same result using a join on the `user_status` table, instead of using a sub-query. Is something like this possible?

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following, which is working great for me:

```
select
  u.id,
  u.name,
  us.status
from
  user u
  left join (
    select
      distinct on (user_id)
      *
    from
      user_status
    order by
      user_id,
      created_at desc
  ) as us on u.id = vs.user_id
where
  u.active = true;
```

This is also more efficient than the query that I had in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select u.id , b.status 
 from user u join user_status b on u.id= b.user_id
 where u.active = true;
 order by b.s.created_at desc limit 1
```

i think this work.
but in your code there is "b" which i did not know what it is.

Comment: Whoops! That `b` should have been an `s`. Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Also, the query that you provided above is not _quite_ the same as the one I wrote above. I believe yours will only return one row every single time. But my query above returns multiple rows. Any ideas on how to adjust it so that it will return the correct number of rows?

Comment: as i see the two queries return the same results. i a so sorry that i can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` syntax does not directly offer order or limit as options; so strictly speaking you cannot achieve what you want directly as a join. I believe the easiest way to resolve your question is to use a joined subquery, like this:

```
select
       u.id
     , u.name
     , s.status
from user u
left join (
          select
               user_id
             , status
             , row_number() over(partition by user_id
                                 order by created_at desc) as rn
          from user_status s
          ) s on u.id = s.userid and s.rn = 1
where u.active = true;
```

Here the analytic function `row_number()` combined with the `over()` clause enables the subsequent join condition `and s.rn=1` to take advantage of both ordering and limiting the joined rows via the calculation of the rn value.

**nb** *a correlated subquery within the select clause (as used in the question's query) acts like a left join because it can return NULL. If that effect isn't needed or desired you can change to an inner join.*

It is possible to move that subquery into a CTE, but unless there are compelling reasons to do so I prefer using the more traditional form  seen above.

An alternative approach (*for Postgres 9.3 or later*) is to use a `lateral` join which is quite similar to the original subquery, but as it becomes part of the from clause is likely to be more efficient that using that subquery in the select clause.

```
select
       u.id
     , u.name
     , s.status
from user u
left join lateral (
       select user_status.status 
       from user_status
       where user_status.user_id = u.id 
       order by user_status.created_at desc 
       limit 1
       ) s ON true
where u.active = true;
```

Comment: Using `distinct on ()` instead of a window function is typically faster.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it by converting the subquery into a with clause and use it in the join

Comment: Do you know whether your solution would be more or less efficient than the sub-query solution that I gave in my question?

Comment: In your subquery you are hitting the user_status  for each id whereas if you materialize it using With you basically reuse it. Rest your explain plan will tell you.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @Ted Without knowing that I couldn't comment at that time you marked it down.

Comment: that doesn't change the fact that you should have waited until you were able to comment